# How to run a script for multiple files in a directory?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, directory

I have a script that I want to run for all files in a directory. All examples I can find use file which I know no longer works in python 3.x.

So this is what I tried before realising that:

```
import sys, os, cv2

path = 'C:\\Users\\telli\\Desktop\\Test Shapes\\Shapes\\Squares'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            os.system ('C:\\Users\telli\\Desktop\\test.py {}'.format(root + '\\' + file))
```

So what should I change it to? I've seen to use `open` but i'm not sure hot to exactly.

Also could you show me a line of code that would leave out a certain file/folder in the main folder?

I tried this but nothing happens:

```
import sys, os

path = 'C:\\Users\\telli\\Desktop\\Test Shapes\\Shapes\\Squares'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        img = cv2.imread(file)
        #print(img)

        #Converting the image to Grayscale
        grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(grey,127,255,1)

        im2,contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours.sort(key = len)

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        #os.system('C:\\Users\telli\\Desktop\\test.py {}'.format(root + '\\' + file))
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: the python 2 `file` function isn't being used here... this code should work in Python 3 (well, at least, the issue won't be the `file` funciton)

Comment: Why the inner loop? That is your problem. Just use for `for file in os.listdir(path)` and remove the inner loop.